# Summarising MONTH value

Tags: sql

I have a simple statement that starts:

```
SELECT a.product, MONTH(a.saledate) AS Month, Count(*) AS Total
```

Which yields, for example,

```
Product          Month        Total

Bike               8               1000
```

Please can anyone advise if it's possible to add the month's name to this query and also, is it possible to get a monthly total to appear as well?

Thanks!

Comment: The answers are yes, and yes. (Add sample table data and the expected result. Also show us the whole query.)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: It's gotta be MySQL .. the nonstandard aggregation gives it away. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: What do You mean by monthy total? Next to total for each row total value for this month?

Comment: what DBMS you use ?

Comment: Thanks for the very speedy responses. It's a work database;  I just need a pointer to getting a total by month, so for example I can have 'Monthly Total' as a field.

Comment: Grumble. "It's a car I use for work. I just need a pointer to the engine, because the "check engine" light is on."  Please. What make and model of database software are you using, Mr. @WillF ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query in your example counts all the rows in your table, then presents that count next to a randomly chosen row's product and sale date. That's -- almost certainly -- not what you want.  MySQL is quirky that way. Other DBMSs reject your example query.

If you want to display a monthly summary of product sold, here's the basic query:

```
 SELECT a.product, 
        LAST_DAY(a.saledate) AS month_ending,
        COUNT(*) AS Total
   FROM table a
  GROUP BY a.product, LAST_DAY(a.saledate)
```

[The `LAST_DAY()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) is a great way to extract month and year from a date.

Finally, if you want to display the text name of the month, you can use [the `DATE_FORMAT()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to do that. `%b` as a format specifier gives a three-letter month name, and `%M` gives the full month name. So this query will do it.

```
 SELECT a.product, 
        LAST_DAY(a.saledate) AS month_ending,
        DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(a.saledate), '%M %Y')) AS month
        COUNT(*) AS Total
   FROM table a
  GROUP BY a.product, LAST_DAY(a.saledate)
```

In SQL Server 2012+ you can use [the `EOMONTH()` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213020.aspx) in place of `LAST_DAY()`.

In SQL Server 2008+ you can use [`DATENAME(mm, a.saledate)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) to retrieve the month name from a date.

Comment: Firstly, apologies for my vagueness. I'm using T-SQL, not MySQL - I should have been clearer. Thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: Sadly I don't have SQL Server 2012+ - we use 2008R2. So the EOMONTH() function can't be used, unfortunately. Cheers re DATENAME.

Comment: You know, your favorite search engine will give you helpful information if you ask for "eomonth for sql server 2008"

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of getting month name

1)

```
SUBSTRING('JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC ', (MONTH(a.saledate) * 4) - 3, 3)
```

2)

```
DATENAME(month, a.saledate)
```

Some poeple say You might be using MYSQL:

Then getting month name will be:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME( a.saledate);
```